# Email Notification when someone modifies and saves the document (Word, excel...)

Tags: excel, ms-word

I have few files shared with my team, in the document they will update the points. So rather than checking document everytime regarding updates, I want to have notification via mail informing that changes happened in so and so document. Is there a way to implement this? I have no idea which programming language or method to be used??
Can you suggest me a way to implement?

Comment: Is this what you are after https://support.office.com/en-in/article/Send-a-Word-document-for-review-by-using-e-mail-37d5a84e-0a1c-48b6-bb15-b4f9f6c66f23?ui=en-US&rs=en-IN&ad=IN&fromAR=1

Comment: An email may be a bit much. Use an SMS gateway to send an IM text to your phone.

Comment: In MS-office option is good, Thanks  YVXS. But rather than sending document in the mail, its just has to give information that file has been modified. Also is there a way to happen automatically when user closes the modified document?

Comment: Its possible, you will have to take `VBA` approach thou. Quit difficult to suggest without looking at it in detail. I assume you have this docs in `sharepoint` or `shared drives`

Comment: How about having a batch file in which we run command prompt commands to verify modified date and calling python script in that to send a mail when modified date changes. Although I dont know whether its correct or not, I was trying but failed at one step.